# Using Models from PSPICE in ISPICE

Tags: spice, library, orcad

How can I use a model from PSPICE into ISpice?

I've been told that Spice models are roughly cross engine compatible.

[Intusoft ISpice](http://www.intusoft.com/icap.htm) has a really easy UI, but doesn't have as many models included as [OrCad  PSpice](http://www.orcad.com/products/orcad-ee-pspice-designer/overview)

I wanted to shift a model for a level 2 mosfet accorss from the redistributable eval.lib:

So took the following and put it into a file called: `extramod.lib` in `C:\spice8\pr`,
then in ISpice SpiceNet, did the `File->Update Part Database`, which went through without error.
But now I can't find my new parts.

```
.MODEL MN4016A NMOS LEVEL=2 VTO=1.45 TOX=1000E-10 NSUB=4.7E16
+XJ=3U LD=2U UO=625 UCRIT=1E5 UEXP=0.45 UTRA=0.25 RSH=15 
+NEFF=2.5 VMAX=1E6 CGBO=3E-10 CGDO=10E-10 CGSO=10E-10 CJSW=2F
+NFS=4E12  GAMMA=2.2 LAMBDA=0.02
*
.MODEL MP4016A PMOS LEVEL=2 VTO=-1.5 TOX=1000E-10 NSUB=7.6E15
+XJ=3U LD=1.5U UO=225 UCRIT=3E5 UEXP=.5 UTRA=0.25 RSH=15
+NEFF=2.5 VMAX=1E5 CGBO=3E-10 CGDO=10E-10 CGSO=10E-10 CJSW=1F
+NFS=1E12  GAMMA=1.8 LAMBDA=0.02
```

Answer (score 1):

ISPice has a slighty different set of requirements on its models:

You can find a manual for this in `C:/spice8/Adding_SPICE_Model.pdf`.
The key parts are:

> 1) ...separate each part by using  as delimiters. This means that
>   the netlist will be enclosed by a line that starts with 5 or more
>   asterisks. Therefore, add this to the top and bottom of your netlist
>   (the line of ). Even if you are only adding one part, you still 
>   need to implement this procedure...
>
> 2) ... After the ***** line marking where your part begins, you will
>   be adding a *SRC=  line to link to SpiceNet's part browser...
>
> ***** 
>   *SRC=Part_Number;SubCkt;PartType;SubType;Notes

So you should have something like, in your library file.
The rest of your procedure is fine.

```
*From OrCad Eval (free to reuse)
*****
*SRC=PSpice_PMOS;MP4016A;MOSFETs P;Gen. Purpose;L2
.MODEL MP4016A PMOS LEVEL=2 VTO=-1.5 TOX=1000E-10 NSUB=7.6E15
+XJ=3U LD=1.5U UO=225 UCRIT=3E5 UEXP=.5 UTRA=0.25 RSH=15
+NEFF=2.5 VMAX=1E5 CGBO=3E-10 CGDO=10E-10 CGSO=10E-10 CJSW=1F
+NFS=1E12  GAMMA=1.8 LAMBDA=0.02
******

*From OrCad Eval (free to reuse)
*****
*SRC=PSpice_NMOS;MN4016A;MOSFETs N;Gen. Purpose;L2
.MODEL MN4016A NMOS LEVEL=2 VTO=1.45 TOX=1000E-10 NSUB=4.7E16
+XJ=3U LD=2U UO=625 UCRIT=1E5 UEXP=0.45 UTRA=0.25 RSH=15 
+NEFF=2.5 VMAX=1E6 CGBO=3E-10 CGDO=10E-10 CGSO=10E-10 CJSW=2F
+NFS=4E12  GAMMA=2.2 LAMBDA=0.02
******
```